# Is there a way to set a non-string bean property using c:set?

Tags: jsf, facelets, el

In my JSF 2.1 facelets environment, I would like to set a bean property of int type:

facelets template:

```
<c:set target="#{mybean}" property="size" value="3"/>
```

java setter:

```
public void setSize(int size){
  this.size = size;
}
```

But it throws an exception:

```
javax.el.ELException: Can't set property 'size' on class 'MyBean' to value '3'.
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.setValue(BeanELResolver.java:398)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
```

Looking into the code of BeanELResolver, I have noticed that the value "3" is unfortunately simply passed to the setter method without any coercion, which obviously does not work. It is a pity that BeanELResolver does not make use of the type knowledge it has there.

Is there a way to coerce the value to an int somehow? I already tried value="#{3}" but this yields a Long. Next thing that comes to my mind is value="#{f:toInt(3)}" using a custom function.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the problem you're having. I created a simple `RequestScoped` bean with a single property.

```
public class IndexBean {
    private int value;

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then When I used a defered expression (the one that starts with a `#`) within the `target` attribute...

```
<c:set target="#{indexBean}" property="value" value="5"/>
<h:outputText value="#{indexBean.value}"/>
```

...I received a JSP exception, saying

> Its illegal to specify deferred expression for dynamic attribute.

...which lead me to change the expression to be immediate evaluated.

```
<c:set target="${indexBean}" property="value" value="5"/>
<h:outputText value="#{indexBean.value}"/>
```

...and the value was correctly shown on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation. It seems to make quite a difference in which environment you are. In my case, I have Mojarra 2.1.21 and I believe to have read that in facelets environment, ${} and #{} are evaluated the same way. At least I get the same exception as before

Answer (score 0):

How about using `fmt:formatNumber`?

```
<fmt:formatNumber var="i" type="number" value="3" />
<c:set target="#{mybean}" property="size" value="${i}"/>
```